# CSS class not inheriting

Tags: html, css

I have a blog of code written such as this:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="statusbox">
      <div class="cleft">some stuff</div>
      <div class="cright">some more stuff</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS code for it:

```
.box{padding:10px; border: 1px black solid;width: inherit;}
.statusbox{border-bottom: 2px #736f6e solid;}
.cleft{float:left;width:84%;vertical-align:middle;min-height:50px;margin-right:10px;padding-top: 5px;}
.cright{float:right;width:15%;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle;min-height:50px;padding-top: 5px;}
```

The issue I'm having is that the structure is not obeyed in terms of the CSS layout. Whilst `cleft` and `cright` show correctly, they are not being embedded within `statusbox` and `box`. `box` and `statusbox` just clump up together, just above the "some stuff".

Here's an image of what I'm currently getting: [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `statusBox`

Floated elements do not contribute to the height of the parent. Since both of your elements are floated, then the parent has no height. Adding `overflow: hidden` changes that.

Comment: Peter Paul Koch (aka PPK) has a nice article about clear floats with overflow: [PPK: CSS clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: I suggest using `overflow:auto` rather than `hidden`. It's the usual way of giving parent the size of their child elements consumed space.(still +1 from me)

Comment: I generally use `hidden` to avoid accidental scrollbars.